# Android 4.4 SQLite Not Updating

Tags: android, sqlite, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a fully functional SQLite database in my Android App which works perfect on my testing devices (Android 4.0 - 4.3), but I have a user running KitKat and they are unable to update the database.  To summarize my code, I have a user click a switch, then asks whether they want to make the change, if so it updates the database table.

Here is my calls to the database from the Activity:

```
 StatusData statusData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_macro);

    statusData = new StatusData(getBaseContext());

 }

 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    switch (v.getId())
        case R.id.switchOffSeason:
        String season,
        seasonHeading = "";
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // set dialog message
        if (switchOffSeason.isChecked()) {
            season = "This will delete all your current settings and default to the standard diet.  This cannot be undone";
            seasonHeading = "Set Standard Diet";
        } else {
            season = "This will delete all your current settings and default to Off-Season diet.  This cannot be undone.";
            seasonHeading = "Set Off-Season Diet";
        }
        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(seasonHeading);

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage(season)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                String passedTask = "offSeason";
                                dropTable task = new dropTable(passedTask);
                                task.execute(passedTask);

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                if (switchOffSeason.isChecked()) {
                                    switchOffSeason.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    switchOffSeason.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();


 private class dropTable extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String task;

    public dropTable(String passedTask) {
        super();
        task = passedTask;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if (task.equals("reset")) {
            String offSeason = statusData.profileTable()[10];
            profileTable = statusData.profileTable();

            statusData.dropReloadMacrosTable(new String[] {
                    profileTable[11], profileTable[12], profileTable[13],
                    profileTable[14], profileTable[15], profileTable[16],
                    profileTable[17], offSeason });
        } else if (task.equals("offSeason")) {
            if (switchOffSeason.isChecked()) {
                statusData.updateFieldProfile(new String[] { "offseason",
                        "1" });
            } else {
                statusData.updateFieldProfile(new String[] { "offseason",
                        "0" });
            }
            String offSeason = statusData.profileTable()[10];
            statusData.dropReloadMacrosTable(new String[] {
                    profileTable[11], profileTable[12], profileTable[13],
                    profileTable[14], profileTable[15], profileTable[16],
                    profileTable[17], offSeason });
        }
        return "Executed";
    }
```

Here is my StatusData (Database) class:

```
    public void updateFieldProfile(String updateArray[]) {
    open();

    Log.i("log", "in method");
    String fieldToUpdate = updateArray[0];
    String valueToUpdate = updateArray[1];
    String query = "UPDATE PROFILE SET " + fieldToUpdate + "="
            + "= ?";
    Log.i("logQuery", query);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {valueToUpdate});
    c.moveToFirst();
    c.close();
    db.close();

}
```

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific than "unable to update"?

Comment: I would recommend using     SQLiteDatabase#execSQL()     or     SQLiteDatabase#update()

Comment: Where is the DB located? If it's 4.4 specific most likely it's a security issue, there were some changes in various bits to lock things down.

Comment: @CL the updates to the database are not stored for this particular switch, but they are for other inputs using similar coding techniques.